# Tar - split files

Tags: linux, compression, tar

i am using the following command to backup and sql file:

```
tar -zcvf "$BACKUP_DST/$FILE_NAME.tgz" "$BACKUP_DST/$FILE_NAME.sql"
```

i want to make sure the compressed file wont be larger then 300mb, if it exceeds 300mb, split it into several files.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `tar` has functionality built-in to split at an arbitrary size (there is `-M` for multi-volume, but this relies on the destination media detecting an out-of-space condition), but there are two things you could do:

1. Generate a single tar.gz file in the usual way, then use the `split` command to divide it into sections (and `cat` to join them back together for decompression).
2. Use [dar](http://dar.linux.free.fr/) instead of tar, since this has splitting functionality built in (amongst a lot of other features that tar doesn't have). For example

   `$ dar -c "$BACKUPNAME" -g "$INPUTFILE.sql" -s300M -z`

Comment: dar sounds interesting, how would i run this command in dar?

Comment: how about using tar with --tape-length and -M ?

Comment: I added an example `dar` command. I just tested `--tape-length` and it doesn't work with compressed archives, repeatedly overwrites the same .tar file without changing the name, and requires you to hit ENTER after each "slice".